# passport.use returns bad request

Tags: express, passport.js

Please find the below code for more information.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//////////////////passport local strategy///////////////////
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
    if(username==password){
        return done(null,{username:username,firstName:'Alice'});
    }
    return done(null,false,{message: 'Unable to login'});
}))

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user);
});



app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local'),function(req,res){
    console.log(req.user);
    res.json(req.user);
})
```

As I have getting 400 bad request for both success and failure when form is submitted by `POST` method .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function (req, username, password, done) { //your signup or login logic });
```

Where 'username' and 'password' are the names of the fields in my form:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholeder="username" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" placeholeder="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
    </form> <br />
```

My router is defined like this:

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/signup',
        failureFlash : true
    }));
```

More info on passport authentication: [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)